# cyclic negative number generation in C++

Tags: c++

I have requirement as follows.

I have to generate increment negative numbers from -1 to -100 which is used a unique id for a request. Like it should be like this: -1, -2, -3, ...-100, -1, -2, and so on. How can I do this effectively? I am not supposed to use Boost. C++ STL is fine. I prefer to write simple function like int GetNextID() and it should generate ID. Request sample program on how to do this effectively?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 4):

```
int ID = -1;
auto getnext = [=] mutable {
    if (ID == -100) ID = -1;
    return ID--;
};
```

Fairly basic stuff here, really. If you have to ask somebody on the Interwebs to write this program for you, you should really consider finding some educational material in C++.

Comment: is it enumerate from -1 to -100?

Comment: Looks like it only goes from -1 to -99 ?

Answer (score 2):

I love the functor solution:

```
template <int limit> class NegativeNumber
{
public:
    NegativeNumber() : current(0) {};

    int operator()()
    {
        return -(1 + (current++ % limit));
    };
private:
    int current;
};
```

Then, you can define any generator with any limit and use it:

```
NegativeNumber<5> five;
NegativeNumber<2> two;

for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
    std::cout << "limit five: " << five() << "\tlimit two: " << two() << '\n';
```

You can also pass the generator as parameter to another function, with each funtor with its own state:

```
void f5(NegativeNumber<5> &n)
{
    std::cout << "limit five: " << n() << '\n';
}

void f2(NegativeNumber<2> &n)
{
    std::cout << "limit two: " << n() << '\n';
}

f5(five);
f2(two);
```

If you don't like the template solution to declare the limit, there's also the no-template version:

```
class NegativeNumberNoTemplate
{
public:
    NegativeNumberNoTemplate(int limit) : m_limit(limit), current(0) {};

    int operator()()
    {
        return -(1 + (current++ % m_limit));
    };
private:
    const int m_limit;
    int current;
};
```

Using as argument to a function works in the same way, and it's internal state is transfered as well:

```
void f(NegativeNumberNoTemplate &n)
{
    std::cout << "no template: " << n() << '\n';
}

NegativeNumberNoTemplate notemplate(3);
f(notemplate);
```

I hope you don't want to use it with threading, they're not thread safe ;)

[Here](http://ideone.com/fYHQg5) you have all the examples; hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even a simple problem like this could lead you to several approximations, both in the algorithmic solution and in the concrete usage of the programming language.

This was my first solution using C++03. I preferred to switch the sign after computing the value.

```
#include <iostream>

int GetNextID() {
    // This variable is private to this function. Be careful of not calling it
    // from multiple threads!
    static int current_value = 0;

    const int MAX_CYCLE_VALUE = 100;

    return - (current_value++ % MAX_CYCLE_VALUE) - 1;
}

int main()
{
    const int TOTAL_GETS = 500;

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_GETS; ++i)
        std::cout << GetNextID() << std::endl;
}
```

A different solution taking into account that **the integer modulo in C++ takes the sign of the dividend** (!) as commented in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls)

```
#include <iostream>

int GetNextID() {
    // This variable is private to this function. Be careful of not calling it
    // from multiple threads!
    static int current_value = 0;

    const int MAX_CYCLE_VALUE = 10;

    return (current_value-- % MAX_CYCLE_VALUE) - 1;
}

int main()
{
    const int TOTAL_GETS = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_GETS; ++i)
        std::cout << GetNextID() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like.... (haven't compiled)

```
class myClass
{
     int number = 0;
     int GetValue ()
     {
         return - (number = ((number+1) % 101))
     }
}
```